# Mail app not allowing me to add my outlook(exchange) account

Tags: mail.app, email, ms-office, exchange, hotmail

- At first it stopped getting all my mails from all my hotmail/outlook related account, so I removed it from the preferences
- Then now I am trying to add it back and it's giving me this screen.

[image]

If anyone else had that issue please help fix it.

*NB: Be gentle please I am a noob*

Comment: You can't add a hotmail account as Exchange..  Try the "outlook.com" type account or "other"... I can't test now, but hotmail is not Exchange type unless something changed recently...

Comment: That did help actually, thanks!
So what I did is to set up a not exchange account just a normal email and it did it magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up the normal way, just add email and it did it magic.

## Edit

Well someone mentioned that it shouldn't be an exchange account, for what's worth I did the set up 2~3 years ago I couldn't remember.
So what I did is:

## 1. Go to `system preferences > Internet Accounts > Add other accounts`

[image]

## 2. Then select Mail Account

[image]

That's it.